# Use external file for templating in backbonejs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I would like to use external file for templating in backbonejs. I searched in google but could not find any suitable solution.

Could anyone say how to do that ??

Comment: In these scenarios I declare the templates in a jsp file(new file) and include the jsp in the required jsp file and render these templates using backbonejs view. Did you try this way?

Answer (score 1):

By external file, you mean storing the template in html files and read it? If so, you need one of the module loaders such as RequireJS (See the [requirejs text plugin](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#text)) or browserify (with the [stringify middleware](http://johnpostlethwait.github.io/stringify/)).

Comment: Chetan Sastry - thanks for your reply. Actually I would like to store templates in a js file with  `<script type="text/template" id="search_template"></script>`  this format. Then I would like to call them from backbonejs view.

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring the templates in a new jsp file and include it in main jsp file. The backbonejs view declared for main jsp can render these new templates.

Comment: Could you say how can I do that?? Could you show some examples ??   Thanks